# Which Linux file system is my folder on?

Tags: linux, installation, disk-space, anaconda

I have an error trying to install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) that I don't have enough disk space. I tried to check the affirmation of the installer by running `df -h` because I am not the administrator of the machine and I am not so sure how much disk space is there and how it is distributed. It looks like this:

```
~$ df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         24G   12K   24G   1% /dev
tmpfs                       4.8G  1.1M  4.8G   1% /run
/dev/dm-0                    35G   34G     0 100% /
none                        4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         24G     0   24G   0% /run/shm
none                        100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/mapper/root-scratch    237G   60M  225G   1% /scratch
172.19.8.10:/pack            99G   84G   11G  90% /pack
hpc-nfs.srv.aau.dk:/deepnn   80G  3.2G   77G   4% /storage
```

But **I don't know how to interpret that**. Do I have space for my installation which should need under 1GB?

In other words, **which of these file systems am I trying to install it to?**

This is the installation folder:

```
Anaconda2 will now be installed into this location:
/users/groupm/ernest/anaconda2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your home directory is mounted at:

```
/dev/dm-0
```

which has less than a Gb left. it looks like `/storage` is where you wanna be installing to... though.. it's a NFS so you may have some I/O problems if you're gonna be running anaconda2

(i don't know if this is "acceptable" but) try and create a working folder in `/dev/myanaconda2`

Comment: okay, then I don't want to use `/storage` if that may lead to other problems. So I would try `/dev/myanaconda2` like you suggest. Can you help me do that? I tried `cd`ing to that "drive" and couldn't make it. Thanks!

Comment: sudo mkdir /dev/myanaconda2 && sudo chmod 700 /dev/myanaconda2 && sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) /dev/myanaconda2 && touch /dev/myanaconda2/testies.test

Comment: You got the mount point (`/`) and device (`/dev/dm-0`) backwards. Also, `/dev` is not an appropriate location for random stuff. It’s for devices and nothing but. It’s also a ramdisk here. Last but not least: The OP said he’s not an administrator, so it’s unlikely he has root access.

Answer (score 2):

Your `/users/` directory would be located here:

```
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
[…]
/dev/dm-0                    35G   34G     0 100% /
[…]
```

Generally the way you can figure this stuff out is `/` means “root” which is where your core system should be, but the other massive clue is that `100%` under the `Used` column.

#### Figuring out disk usage.

If you now want to drill down to find out what might be eating up space is to run this [disk usage (`du`)](http://ss64.com/bash/du.html) command:

```
sudo du -sh /
```

Chances are your own home directory has some stuff eating up space so running this `du` command will tell you where exactly in your home directory something is taking up space.

```
du -sh /users/groupm/ernest/
```

#### But all that said…

With all of that said, it’s hard to say how your system is setup since you clearly have more storage under `/storage`. So perhaps you should use that as install target before you go and clean things up on your system? Don’t know; too idiosyncratic to your setup.

Answer (score 2):

The `df` command also accepts a path. That way you can go from this:

```
fuzzy@server ~ $ df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                             10M  8.0K   10M   1% /dev
/dev/md125                       50G   35G   13G  75% /
tmpfs                           3.2G  908K  3.2G   1% /run
shm                              16G   16K   16G   1% /dev/shm
cgroup_root                      10M     0   10M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md124                      124M   28M   90M  24% /boot
/dev/md126                       99G  9.0G   90G  10% /var/lib/mysql
temp                            2.0G  974M  1.1G  48% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg0-Homes            20G   11G  8.9G  55% /home
/dev/mapper/vg0-SCM             4.8G  1.5G  3.3G  32% /var/scm
/dev/mapper/vg0-WebDataThin     591G  261G  331G  45% /var/www
/dev/mapper/vg0-DNS             488M  6.2M  472M   2% /var/bind
/dev/mapper/vg0-temp             99G   60M   99G   1% /mnt/temp
/dev/mapper/vg0-Syncthing        99G  744M   98G   1% /home/syncthing
/dev/mapper/vg0-Docker           50G  5.7G   44G  12% /var/lib/docker
/dev/mapper/vg0-LXC             100G  849M   98G   1% /var/lib/lxc
/dev/mapper/vg0-VirtualBox      148G  115G   33G  78% /home/vbox
/dev/mapper/vg0-VM--Win8--Data   99G   98G  1.3G  99% /mnt/vm-win8-data
fuzzy@server ~ $ pwd -L
/home/fuzzy
```

To this:

```
fuzzy@server ~ $ df -h .
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg0-Homes   20G   11G  8.9G  55% /home
```

It works somewhat like `pwd -P`:

```
fuzzy@server ~ $ ln -s /var/www
fuzzy@server ~ $ cd www
fuzzy@server ~/www $ df -h .
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg0-WebDataThin  591G  261G  331G  45% /var/www
```